# Retrieve email address of Global Address List selection

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to open the global address list in Excel VBA and select the recipient and populate an Excel userform with the email address.

It populates the next entry in the GAL not the one I select. I adapted some code from here. Looking further it will display the right user but only if one person has that surname.

```vb
Private Sub cmdSetProjectMember1_Click()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog
Dim oGAL As AddressList
Dim myAddrEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim sAliasName As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim EmailAddress As String

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oGAL = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List")
Set oDialog = olApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog

With oDialog
    .AllowMultipleSelection = False
    .InitialAddressList = oGAL
    .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True

    If .Display Then
        sAliasName = oDialog.Recipients.Item(1).Name
        Set myAddrEntry = oGAL.AddressEntries(sAliasName)
        Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
    End If
End With

If Not exchUser Is Nothing Then
    FirstName = exchUser.FirstName
    LastName = exchUser.LastName
    EmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    '...
    MsgBox "You selected contact: " & vbNewLine & _
      "FirstName: " & FirstName & vbNewLine & _
      "LastName:" & LastName & vbNewLine & _
      "EmailAddress: " & EmailAddress
End If

UserForm1.TextBox5.Value = EmailAddress

Set olApp = Nothing
Set oDialog = Nothing
Set oGAL = Nothing
Set myAddrEntry = Nothing
Set exchUser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use the following line:

```
Set myAddrEntry = oGAL.AddressEntries(sAliasName)
```

Change your code to

```
  If .Display Then
    Set myAddrEntry = oDialog.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry
    Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
  End If
```

Comment: My god I have been pulling my hair out on that for days as well. It works  thanks , could not see it.

Comment: If the post answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!